# Convert Python list of duplicate date entries/values to Pandas Dataframe sorted by date

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, dataframe

How can I convert a list of multiple entries, dates, and values to a Pandas Dataframe based on date?  For example:

Given the following list:

```
list_ex = [{'Date': '12/31/2018', 'A': 'N/A'}, 
{'Date': '09/30/2018', 'A': '$5.75'}, 
{'Date': '06/30/2018', 'A': '$5.07'}, 
{'Date': '03/31/2018', 'A': '$3.27'}, 
{'Date': '12/31/2018', 'B': 'N/A'}, 
{'Date': '09/30/2018', 'B': '$56,576.00'}, 
{'Date': '06/30/2018', 'B': '$52,886.00'}, 
{'Date': '03/31/2018', 'B': '$51,042.00'}]
```

How can we convert that to a Dataframe that looks like this (also, where will be 4 or 5 additional columns to this):

```
        Date      A             B
0  2018-12-31     N/A         N/A
1  2018-09-30   $5.75         $56,576.00
2  2018-06-30   $5.07         $52,886.0
3  2018-03-31   $3.27         $51,042.00
```

I've performed multiple searches but could not find any examples that would help with this.  Consequently, I have made two bad attempts but am not coming close to the desired output.

Attempt 1: I converted the strings values to dates and then hoped that the data frame creation would 'automagically' group by date, but that obviously didn't work since every new addition has a new index.  Attempt 1 resulted in the same (basically) df.

```
for i in list_ex:
i['Date'] = datetime.datetime.strptime(i['Date'], '%m/%d/%Y')

# Print Pandas dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(list_ex) 
print(df)
```

Attempt 2: Sort by date.  This obviously failed since it just sorted by date and kept the same number of rows.

```
new_df = pd.sort_values('Date')
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not the most simple or efficient answer, but this works. Basically I'm creating two DataFrame objects, getting rid of all of the nan's and then merging them on the 'Date' column.

```
import pandas as pd

list_ex = [{'Date': '12/31/2018', 'A': 'N/A'},
           {'Date': '09/30/2018', 'A': '$5.75'},
           {'Date': '06/30/2018', 'A': '$5.07'},
           {'Date': '03/31/2018', 'A': '$3.27'},
           {'Date': '12/31/2018', 'B': 'N/A'},
           {'Date': '09/30/2018', 'B': '$56,576.00'},
           {'Date': '06/30/2018', 'B': '$52,886.00'},
           {'Date': '03/31/2018', 'B': '$51,042.00'}]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=list_ex, columns=['Date', 'A']).dropna()
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=list_ex, columns=['Date', 'B']).dropna()

df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='Date')

print(df3)
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `groupby()` method in combination with the `.agg` method like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list_ex)

df = df.groupby('Date').agg({'A': lambda x: list(x)[0],
                             'B': lambda x: list(x)[1]}).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
    Date        A       B
0   03/31/2018  $3.27   $51,042.00
1   06/30/2018  $5.07   $52,886.00
2   09/30/2018  $5.75   $56,576.00
3   12/31/2018  N/A     N/A
```